# Can't run NPM packages after node reinstall anymore

Tags: node.js, npm

Some time ago I tried installing a NPM package and had some trouble doing so. In order to fix that problem, I messed around with node and NPM and now nothing is working anymore. I can't run any NPM installs without getting an EACCES error despite being the admin user on my machine (mac).

Also, I can't use any of the packages that I installed anymore. If I run `gulp watch` in a directory where I previously worked with gulp all the time, I get an error saying `-bash: gulp: command not found`

I tried reinstalling node and npm numerous times using different installation approaches: nvm, Brew, directly from node website (the latter is what worked the best but still I have the problems described above)

This is driving me crazy and I can't work on anything until I find a fix for this

Comment: did you follow these [guidelines](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)?

Comment: Please share the logs or try to change your directory permission of /usr/bin/library and add you as a user

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are having trouble with global and local installations of npm packages:

When you install a package with (npm install -g something) it will be installed globally in /usr/local/lib/node_modules directory

But if you install something without (-g) it will be installed locally in the project directory under the node_modules subfolder

I recommend cleaning everything you have installed regarding node.js and performing  a new clean installation of it.